# My minecraft is giving this error [Unrecognized VM option 'UseConcMarkSweepGC']

Tags: java, minecraft

I'm trying to enter Minecraft Forge 1.12.2 but it ends up giving this error [Unrecognized VM option 'UseConcMarkSweepGC'], I don't know what to do anymore:

I already changed the java version and put it in the Java JDK 1.8 version.

[Unrecognized VM option 'UseConcMarkSweepGC'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dZF5.png)

[my minecraft configuration is like this '-Xmx1G -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode -XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy -Xmn128M'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpUtq.png)

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: How is this Ubuntu related? The path to the Java executable is in DOS/Windows format. Also you seem to have uploaded the same screenshot twice, is that intended?

Comment: The answer to your seemingly non-Ubuntu problem is right there in your configuration string (argumentos do JVM).

Answer (score 0):

Do java --version and let me know what version you are running.

From what I can see in the screen shot its Java 17.

Forge or even Vanilla MC 1.12 does not like Java 17. It require Java 8, usually listed as "1.8".

Another options is to remove all of the java arguments and see if its crashes. I doubt I will work with Java 17 thou.